# Issue with the "npm install drizzle" command on Windows

Tags: truffle, drizzle, frontend, npm

I want to install Drizzle.  Running "npm install drizzle" only displays errors and the installation has failed. 
I have been able to install drizzle-react and drizzle-react-components without an issue but how can I install drizzle?

Comment: what's the output of npm install drizzle?

Comment: npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Comment: and so much more error, i just can't write it at all.

Comment: edit your question and add the output given by npm

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/issues/58), "**npm install drizzle** is no longer supported, it's now **npm install @drizzle/store**." Also, Make sure you clear cache using **npm cache clean --force.**

Comment: the problem is still here i've installed the git version 2.22 anche check it but "npm install drizzle" still don't work

Comment: try  git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

Comment: try to add the npm output

Comment: the command don't work again but now i got different errors message

Comment: npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ricca\Drizzle\app\node_modules\websocket
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git C:\Users\Ricca\Drizzle\app\node_modules\websocket: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     C:\Users\Ricca\Drizzle\app\node_modules\websocket
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ricca\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-05T12_36_54_831Z-debug.log

Comment: run rmdir -r node_modules/*/.git/

Comment: the command don't work maybe i don't have some package in my system that is required